# Wi-fi keeps dropping in and out on MacOS 12.6.7 Monterey

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, mac

Wi-fi keeps disconnecting and reconnecting and it only happens on this machine. I tried an update, restart, and ran Wireless Diagnostic and it couldn't solve the issue. It gave me a laundry list of diagnostic files and through a little poking around I saw this:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this or if I'm even on the right track? There are a lot of files and I'm not sure where to look exactly. Thanks

Comment: Test again after switching to the suggested channel, if it's your network. Many WiFi APs/routers will pick what they think is the best channel at boot, if you power-cycle them.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem after updating two days ago.  It's usually fine all day, but it's a real struggle to get my default WiFi to "stick" after the MacBook wakes up in the morning.  For reference: 2021 MacBook Pro w/ M1.  Going to try the update on my older MacBook (2017) to see if it does the same.